# C# Ordinals of Columns of Datatable changed after setting Bindingsource as datasource of Datagridview

Tags: c#, datatable, bindingsource, ordinal

i use a datatable as datasource of my bindingsource.

The columns have the following order and ordinals:

[Before setting the datasource of datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNN68.png)

When I assign the bindingsource to the datasource property of my datagridview the 
ordinals changes:

[Afer settting the datasource of datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET7DI.png)

The last column ("Gesamt") gets the ordinal 0.
How can I avoid this effect?

This is the relevant code:

```
     BsData.DataSource = myPR.PR_Data;  //PR_Data is the datatable ,
                                        //BsData is the bindingsource

     dgvSchoolGrade.DataSource = null;  //dgvSchoolGrade is the Datagridview
      //Before
     dgvSchoolGrade.DataSource = BsData;

     //After
```

Thank you very much in advance!
Sascha

Comment: What are these images showing? It seems to be the `List` property of the `BindingSource` not the `DataTable`. The `DataTable` is not modified.

Comment: The picture shows the the columns of the datatable when I debug the code.

Comment: Damn! I found out there was a ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event implemented, which manipulated the column order. I have removed it and it works like a charm.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you very much for you fast help.